# Не отображается файл сториборда после сброса версии остальных файлов в проекте XCode. SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

Всем привет, я начинающий, не бросайте тапками пожалуйста.
В общем у меня в проекте отлетел файл сториборд, случилось это после того как я наклацал чего то не того при попытке делегирования от одного контроллера к другому, посыпались ошибки которые я решить не смог, про гит хаб я до этого момента увы не слышал и мне не пришло ничего умнее, как откатить все файлы при помощи  TextEdit до версии, когда все было ок, ошибки из кода пропали, но вместо сотриборда теперь просто пустой белый фон, при том, что сам файл отдельно от проекта открывается и содержит в себе все как и было, а внутри проекта- нет.
Я подозреваю возможно его нужно как то заново законектить где то в системных файлах проекта но где бы это могло быть сам я не нашел, а как прикрутить сториборд обратно не нашел в гугле.
Подскажите пожалуйста как прикрутить назад к проекту файл сториборда

Вот так ведет себя файл вне проекта,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так отображается файл в проекте.
[image: А вот так он ведет себя в проекте]

К слову все файлы, которые находятся ниже меин сотриборда отображаются теперь точно так же- пустым фоном...

Comment: `отдельно от проекта открывается и содержит в себе все как и было` - открывается в текстовом редакторе в виде  xml или в икскоде в виде макета?

Comment: Именно в икскоде и там все так как и было в самом проекте

Comment: Не совсем понятно как он у вас "отлетел", если он все же открывается вне проекта (и в проект я как понимаю тоже при этом добавлен?). Неплохо бы взглянуть на скриншот, как он сейчас отображается в проекте

Comment: Добавил скрины в сам вопрос. Заметил еще что не отображаются и все вкладки ниже файла сториборда

Comment: А если файл стриборда удалить из проекта и добавить заново?

Comment: Все равно не видно его. Причем если в другой проект закинуть, то его видно. Пробовал создать новый пустой проект и просто закинуть туда все файлы из предыдущего, все ок но бил не собирается теперь

Comment: залейте куда-нибудь свой проект, в котором сториборд не виден я и посмотрю

Comment: Прошу 
https://fex.net/uk/s/dlkrsyx
Благодарю!

Comment: у меня все отображается https://ibb.co/DGs3BDM

Comment: Странно, я уже и посносил все что у меня было, скачал с фекса, а все равно история все та же...
Ладно похоже судьба писать мне с ноля это чудовище, все равно не все понял пока собирал этот конструктор, но в любом случае спасибо за помощь!